# Convert NULL from Python to R using rpy2

Tags: r, python-3.x, null, rpy2

In R often the `NULL` value is used as default. Using Python and RPy2, how can one explicitly provide a `NULL` argument?

`None` is not convertible (`NotImplementedError`), a string 'NULL' will just be converted to a string and result in an error during execution.

Take the following example using the `tsintermittent` package:

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri

numpy2ri.activate()

tsintermittent = importr('tsintermittent')
crost = tsintermittent.crost

ts = np.random.randint(0,2,50) * np.random.randint(1,10,50)

# implicit ok, default w is NULL
# crost(ts)

# explicit - how to do it?
# RRunTimeError - non numeric argument
crost(ts, w='NULL')
# NotImplementedError
crost(ts, w=None)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `r` object to import `as.null` and then call that function. For example:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r

as_null = r['as.null']
is_null = r['is.null']
print(is_null(as_null())) #prints TRUE
```

I didn't try your code because of all of its dependencies, but if `as_null` is defined as above, you should be able to use

```
crost(ts, w=as_null())
```

**Alternatively**, use the `NULL` object definition directly from `robjects`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robj

print(is_null(robj.NULL)) #prints TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, @jpcoleman, I found my preferred solution thanks to this. I have edited to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be because of the quotes in `NULL`.    Not able to check with `rpy2` (because of having installation issues).  Below, is a code that is working with `pyper`

```
from pyper import *
import numpy as np
r=R(use_pandas=True)
ts = np.random.randint(0,2,50) * np.random.randint(1,10,50)
r('library(tsintermittent)')
r.assign('ts1', ts)
r('out <- crost(ts1, w = NULL)')
out1 = r.get('out')
out1.keys()
#['frc.out', 'initial', 'weights', 'components', 'model', 'frc.in']
```

---

Can't test the issue with `rpy2`.  May be backquotes would be an option to read it as it is

```
crost(ts, w = `NULL`)
```