# How to convert None to R NULL

Tags: python, rpy2

After reading [Mapping rpy2 objects to arbitrary python objects](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/robjects_convert.html) I thought the following would allow the conversion of Python None to R NULL:

```py
import rpy2.robjects.conversion as cv
import rpy2.robjects as robjs
from rpy2.robjects import default_converter
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

r_base = importr("base")


def _none2null(none_obj):
    return robjs.r("NULL")


none_converter = cv.Converter("None converter")
none_converter.py2rpy.register(None, _none2null)

with cv.localconverter(default_converter + none_converter):
    filesl = r_base.list_files(pattern=None)
```

However, it fails with the Trace:

```py
NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'NoneType'>'
```

How can this be handled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert NULL from Python to R using rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636932/convert-null-from-python-to-r-using-rpy2)

Comment: No, unfortunately. Using robjs.NULL in the converter function gives the same result

Comment: This is a good question as rpy2 user may wish to have their `None`s auto-converted to `NA`, `NULL` or another R construct. Converter is the proper pattern here and is distinct from manual conversion as in the question linked by @PacketLoss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Converter.register()` method accepts type of an object to convert as the first argument, but you passed an instance. `None` is an instance of `NoneType`:

```
NoneType = type(None)
NoneType() is None   # True
```

and you need to define conversion for `NoneType`, so you can just use:

```
none_converter.py2rpy.register(type(None), _none2null)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!